# Circuit Training makes me feel sick

Tags: circuit-training, nausea

When ever I do circuit training I feel sick for hours afterwards.  I do squats, lunges, bent over rows, push-ups, standing shoulder press, alternate biceps, over heads triceps, and abs and then rest for 60 seconds and do it all over again 2 more times.  I usually do it in the morning but I feel sick even if I eat before my workout.  Does anyone know what could be going on?  Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very common with circuit training. How long have you been doing it? Most people tend to lose the sickness feeling after a few weeks because their cardiovascular endurance catches up to the amount of work it is getting. I train my clients in groups and use circuits a lot. When they first start out, some even throw up. However, the feeling goes away after they get in better shape after a few weeks. That should be the same for you.

Comment: I'd say I'm probably still out of shape

Comment: You can either stick with the current plan and work through the sickness feeling, or back off a little and slowly work your way up to the full workout. Your choice!